# Mi boton comprar deberia mostrar una lista de productos en un contenedor, y no sucede nada al apretarlo ¿como lo soluciono?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto ecomerce propio, aun soy nuevo en react y no se como solucionar el siguiente problema. Tengo un boton que al hacerle click este deberia (mediante un renderizado condicional) mostrar dos posibles respuesta, mostrar: 'el estado es falso' si el carro esta vacio, o caso contrario, motrar los productos comprados por el cliente.

A continuacion voy a mostrar una imagen diciendo las lineas donde se ubica el problema del boton que deberia mostrar una ventana con los productos comprados al presionar "comprar", pero que no funciona:

[image: problema a solucionar en la imagen]

- El boton "comprar", esta ubicado en la linea 49.
- La logica que deberia mostrar la lista de productos al apretar el boton "comprar" va desde la linea 20 a la 27.
- Esta informacion deberia viajar desde el componente "ApiEcommerce.jsx" a "Modal.jsx" y mostrar una lista de los productos comprados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar a la pagina y hacer click en el carrito (icono arriva a la derecha), el renderizado opcional se activa, al hacer click deberia mostrar la lista, caso contrario envia un mensaje por consola diciendo que el estado no esta activado o es falso

Entonces. ¿Como puedo hacer que al apretar el boton comprar, muestre el producto en el componente modal (icono del carrito)?

Github:[Aqui esta mi proyecto](https://github.com/San-dei/duda-stackoverflow.git)  para que puedas analizar el proyecto mas comodamente

Comment: Se supone que, cuando tu le das comprar al producto, este se guarda en el carrito de compras o simplemente le mandas el mensaje que comentas? Porque no logo comprender ese parte.

Comment: Hola buenas, precisamente. Al dar click en el boton comprar, debe almacenarse y mostrarse en el carrito. El carrito es el modal. Espero que halla aclarado tu duda, no dude en preguntar nuevamente!

Comment: El detalle es que antes de que se lo envies al modal, debes crear un objeto, el cual tenga esos datos... Al final debes tener un array de objects donde tengas todos esos datos ¿Eso lo tienes? Porque no logro verlo en tu codigo

Comment: Hola,lamentablemente no tengo nada de eso, no contemple la idea de hacerlo asi, crei que seria mas sencillo

Comment: Buenas, si pones el código en formato de código te lo puedo solucionar. Pero aquí no estás teniendo en cuenta uno de los principios de React. React es una librería inventada por Facebook para evitar la sobrecarga de las aplicaciones,  y no está todo el rato "observando" cambios, lo que tienes que hacer es crear una variable global que se actualice con el React.setState, ya que React funciona por estados, sino... "no se entera", o más bien... no observa cambios.

Comment: genial!,intentare usar el React.setState a ver si funciona entonces, muchas gracias a todos